# C# - List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Items'

Tags: c#, list, listbox

Complete error:

> `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'` does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My task is to save a text file using savefiledialog window, this is the code I am using:

```
public void Create()
        {
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

            save.FileName = "Report.txt";

            save.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(save.OpenFile());

                for (int i = 0; i < _Reports.Items.Count; i++)
                {

                    writer.WriteLine(_Reports.Items[i].ToString());

                }

                writer.Dispose();
                writer.Close();

            }
        }
```

I also initialized the list using

```
List<string> _Reports = new List<string>();
```

but the Items method of the list is not supported. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It should just be `_Reports.Count`, Items is a VB property. You have the same problem inside the for loop, it should be `_Reports[i].ToString()`, remove the Items property.

Comment: @RonBeyer Oh!, Thanks!! works perfectly now.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "Items" property. You can read about List class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

It will be just _Reports.Count

Answer (score 0):

Your error says everything. there is nothing called item with the `List<string>` So your code should be

```
public void Create()
{
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.FileName = "Report.txt";
    save.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";
    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(save.OpenFile());
        for (int i = 0; i < _Reports.Count; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(_Reports[i].ToString());
        }
        writer.Dispose();
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```